# How do you handle a child with two parent options

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are creating an activity builder and I am struggling with a good way to deal with a child one parent with different types.

we have two tables Categories and Activities.
Categories have an id and name
activities have an id and parentid

the activities parentid can be either the id of a category or the id of another activity.
A category has activities each of those activities can have sub activities.
Categories are top tier only, so no categories or activities have sub categories

Now I have two questions
what is the best way to set up the tables.
I've thought about storing them in separate columns, the same column as a string with the id and some sort of flag, column with id and another column with the parent table.

I don't think any of these are very good and would like to know what is.

The other question is how would I pull this table. I know I could do multiple look ups but was wandering if there was a way to do it all in one.

we are using MSSQL 2012

edited to attempt to clarify and add more information

Comment: Can you give a little bit more description, like what is [types categories], what is [activities categories], what is name activities], what is the business relationship, if you give some sample data, then it will help people to help you define schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a big fan of "overloading" in SQL. In other words, a column should contain data that means only one thing. Therefore, I would suggest the following data structure.

Category => Id | Name

Activity => Id | Name | CategoryId not null | ParentActivityId null

This way, every Activity is associated with a Category, and may be associated with a parent Activity.

As far as "pulling"? I assume you mean selecting the data?

```
SELECT a.Name AS ActivityName, c.Name AS ParentName, c.Id AS ParentId
FROM Category c
JOIN Activity a
ON c.Id = a.CategoryId
WHERE a.ParentActivityId IS NULL

UNION 

SELECT a.Name AS ActivityName, c.Name AS ParentName, c.Id AS ParentId
FROM Activity c
JOIN Activity a
ON c.Id = a.ParentActivityId
```

Comment: I will try this out and let you know how it goes. Thanks for the help

Comment: Is there a way to get it to return categories that don't have any activities as well